# Using variables as index on list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have two lists:

```
List1 = [1, 3, 6, 8, 1, 61, 89, ...]  # This is how List1 is declared
List2[1][3][6][8][1][61][89][...]  # This is how I want to access data from List2
```

`List1` is a one one-dimensional list with undefined size (can have 1, 2 or infinite items)

`List2` is a multi-dimensional (nested) list (can be 2d or 3d or infinite)

I wanted to use the lists like this `List2[List1[0]][List1[1]][List1[...]]`; I  want to access the data in `List2` using the data from `List1`.

I tried the following but I got an error

```
 len(List2[List1])
```

How can I access `List2`'s data by using the indexes in `List1`?

Comment: So for the `List1` that you actually show, `[1, 2, ...]`, you want `List2[1][2]...`? In that case you could just use `target = List2; for index in List1: target = target[index]`. Afterwards the element you seek will be assigned to `target`.

Comment: What does `List2[1][3][6][8][1][61][89][...]` mean?

Comment: I have tried to make your examples consistent, please double-check that I've done so correctly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That was exactly what i wanted. Thanks alot!!(I mean the answer, but thanks for correcting my code too.)

Answer (score 0):

`len(List2[List1])` : You are trying to index a `List2` using `List1` while indexing in lists is done using integers.

Try: `len(List2[List1[0]])`